# How to retrieve data from an existing table of dynamo DB using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I'm a beginner in  AWS and Dynamo DB.
I wanted to perform some basic operations like retrieve data from a table in Dynamo DB:

My code:

```
<?php
require 'aws-autoloader.php';
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');    
use Aws\DynamoDb;   
use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException;    
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;   
use Aws\S3\S3Client;   
use Aws\Common\Aws;   
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;     
use aws\Aws\AwsClient;     

$client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([ 'version' => 'latest', 'key' => '******', 'secret' => '*******', 'region' => '********','token'=>'****' ]);

try
{   
    $result = array();
    echo  $response = $client->query([ 'TableName' => 'user_master']); 
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "General ex:\n";
    print_r($result);
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
?>
```

When I run this code I'm getting below exception:

> Operation not found: Query

I'm able to print $client.
I have setup my local PHP environment using XAMPP.

Comment: Hi All,I have done some research and resolved the problem.First I have done the SDK installation after downloading the zip file. Because of this issue i tried installation using composer method and the configuration started working.